# HTML/CSS: How to get some text to align on right and other text on left on same line of table cell

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to get some text to align on left and other text to align on right in table cell for mobile site without success.  Would greatly appreciate any suggestions:

html:

Following code with block defined aligns arrows to right but adds a line break before them so the line becomes two lines--not good.

```
<table></tr>
<td><a href="listproducts.php">Products<span style="display: block" style="text-align:right">>></span></a></td>
</tr></table>
```

This code displays arrows immediately after word Products instead of aligning to right though the arrows do stay on same line.

```
<table></tr>
<td><a href="listproducts.php">Products<span style="display: inline" style="text-align:right">>></span></a></td>
</tr></table>
```

How do you get text on left and arrow on right on same line.  Note: I don't want to go to two cells as this will mess layout up.  Also do not want to have to create images for every one of these links as there are a ton of them.

BTW: Am using a table layout for this as I don't have the css knowledge to do a table free layout.

Thanks.

Comment: You are in for a world of pain if you think tables will be easier here.

Comment: what do you use for mobile websites?

Comment: CSS with media queries - tables are not meant for layout.

Comment: Not tables.  Tables are never appropriate for layout.

Comment: My understanding is media queries are for reponsive websites?  Would that work for a dedicated mobile site?  I think I want to go dedicated as the full website is very complex....would be a bear to convert to one column..so I am paring down for mobile version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, try this.

```
<table style="width:100%;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="listproducts.php">Products<span style="float:right;">>></span></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're welcome. However, I recommend you to learn block elements and store css and html in separate files.

Comment: Actually, the classes for the css are in a separate file however I abbreviated to keep question simple.

Comment: This works well… until the browser starts wrapping the right floating span. Seems impossible to keep it on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

Since the text you want to have floated is purely decorative, it would be best to have it be generated content via CSS.  The container tag you use doesn't really matter, but a heading tag seems most appropriate here.

http://jsfiddle.net/Jk8gq/

```
h1.decorative:after {
    content: '>>';
    float: right;
}

h1.non-decorative span {
    float: right;
}

<h1 class="decorative"><a href="listproducts.php">Products</a></h1>

<h1 class="non-decorative"><a href="listproducts.php">Products</a> <span><a href="#">See All</a></span></h1>
```